# Need to place a model down in Roblox

Tags: lua, roblox

I am currently creating a game in Roblox, and I am not the greatest at scripting in Lua/Roblox. I need to when a player has a model of some sort, is able to place it down in a specific location, and be able to pick it back up at any given time. If there is a way to do it, let me know. --Thanks in advance.

--Unless I have to use a mesh of some sort.

Comment: Its a great idea - but it looks like you’ll need to first learn about how Roblox game objects are represented in code. From there, others here on SO could help you look at that code and figure out how to add the new feature/behavior that you want to add.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're searching is to move a model to a specific CFrame/Vector3 position, then, it's really easy.

***CFrame:***

```
    model.PrimaryPart=model:GetChildren()[math.random(1,#model:GetChildren())]
    model:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(CFrame.new(0,50,0))
```

And with Vector3, it's even easier!

***Vector3:***

```
    model:MoveTo(Vector3.new(0,50,0))
```

Remember, Vector3 has it's limitations, if you're going to use the Vector3 method, remember that the model must be in a clear space, big enough to fit the whole model, otherwise, it will appear in top of any object it finds. That's the thing when you position things with Vector3.

CFrame, unlike Vector3, doens't respect that rule, so you can place the model anywhere (if it isn't anchored, then it probably will fly away if you try to put it inside a wall)